# MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap returns System.err in notification largeicon

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am making radio app which uses shoutcast stream. Everything works well with my app except showing artwork of playing track at notification large icon. I want to use artwork from uri. But it never shows the artwork at largeicon.
 Here is the log

> 11-10 17:28:58.624 21627-21627/****** I/Artwork:
>   /storage/emulated/0/******/Radio/artworks/fb7fb1d9ad.jpg
>
> 11-10 17:28:58.628 21627-21627/****** W/System.err:     at ******
>   .Radyo.nowPlayingN(Radyo.java:684)

```
if(uri==null) {
                Bitmap Largeicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_for_radio);
                notification.setLargeIcon(Largeicon);
            }else {
                try {
                    Log.i("Artwork", uri);
                    Bitmap SavedArtwork = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(uri));
                    notification.setLargeIcon(SavedArtwork);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    notification.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher_for_radio));
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap uriToBitmap(Context c, Uri uri) {
    if (c == null && uri == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(c.getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this

```
Bitmap SavedArtwork = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse("file://"+uri));
```